# Regex to detect #ifdef BUILD_FLAG ... #endif with optional multiple nested #if #elif #endif blocks

Tags: python, regex, parsing, python-re

I'm trying to write a script to detect and remove a #ifdef BUILD_FLAG ... #endif block from files. So something like this will be remove

```
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
...
#endif
```

inside the #ifdef ... #endif, there might be one or more #if #elif #end blocks, so something like this should also be removed

```
#ifdef BUILD_FLAG
  #if ...
    #if ...
    #elif ...
    #endif
  #endif
#endif
```

Note that the indentation is just for more readable, it is not neccesarily formated that way.
My current regex is as follow,

```
BUILD_FLAG_MATCHER = rf'#ifndef\s+{re.escape(build_flag)}\s*' \
                     rf'((#if\s+.*?(#elif\s+.*?)*#endif|[\s\S])*?)\s*#endif|'
modified_content = re.sub(BUILD_FLAG_MATCHER, '', content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Right now it only detect an optional #if... #elif... #endif block, so the second example above will be left with an abundant #endif at the end that should be removed.

I'm wondering if there if a better way/pattern to look for more complex nested blocks as mentioned above. Thank you

Comment: This is possible using PCRL regex tho: https://regex101.com/r/ucLXNW/latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module in python, you could use a recursive regex to match your `BUILD_FLAG` blocks:

```
^\s*#ifdef BUILD_FLAG\n(?:\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n|(\s*#if.*\n(?:\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n|(?1))+\s*#endif\n))*\s*#endif
```

This matches:

- `^` : beginning of line
- `\s*#ifdef BUILD_FLAG\n` : some number of spaces, `#ifdef BUILD_FLAG` and a newline
- `(?:` : a non-capturing group matching either

  1. `\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n` : a line that doesn't start with `#if`; or
  2. `(\s*#if.*\n(?:\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n|(?1))+\s*#endif\n)` : a recursive capturing group matching

  - `\s*#if.*\n` : a line that starts with `#if`
  - `(?:\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n|(?1))+` : either a line that doesn't start with `#if`; or a recursion of this groups pattern
  - `\s*#endif\n` : an `#endif` to match the opening `#if`
- `\s*#endif` : an `#endif` to match the opening `#ifdef`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CsWS3g/2)

Python usage:

```
import regex

pat = regex.compile(r'^\s*#ifdef BUILD_FLAG\n(?:\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n|(\s*#if.*\n(?:\s*(?!#if)\S.*\n|(?1))+\s*#endif\n))*\s*#endif', re.M)

modified_content = pat.sub('', content)
```

Note this regex attempts to be very robust in terms of matching `#if` and `#endif` *only* after optional whitespace at the beginning of a line. If you know that will always be the case, the regex proposed by @HaoWu in their comment is a much cleaner, more efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

i guess that is what your looking for

```
BUILD_FLAG_MATCHER =(?:^(#ifdef BUILD_FLAG)\n((?:.|\n)+?\n#endif))
```

this is the link where i tested the solution [regex playgrond](https://regex101.com/r/x89MaA/1)

Comment: This won't work if internal `#if` blocks are not indented

Comment: See OPs comment "Note that the indentation is just for more readable, it is not neccesarily formated that way"

Comment: It does not work the way I want it to be. I put a more complex example in this link using your pattern: https://regex101.com/r/SUsAUA/2 (it should be able to detect the whole #ifdef BUILD_FLAG ... #endif with multiple #if... #elif... #endif inside)

Comment: so for @Nick i used the shortest way to select the bloc #if, i don't know how to make it more readable seriously.
and for the example you provided, u want to choose the whole block of #if?
like this :
https://regex101.com/r/SUsAUA/3